# Select all rows that contain that are at least a certain date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

Code-

```
df = {'sample_received': {1: 'NaN',
2: 'NaN',
17: 'NaN',
3: 'NaN',
4: 'NaN',
5: 'NaN',
6: 'NaN',
7: 'NaN',
8: 'NaN',
9: 'NaN',
10: 'NaN',
11: 'NaN',
12: 'NaN',
13: 'NaN',
14: '2022-08-01 20:15:28',
15: '2022-08-01 20:12:56',
16: '2022-08-01 20:18:19'},
'result_received': {1: '2022-07-28 12:25:37',
2: '2022-07-30 12:37:37',
17: '2022-07-28 12:45:37',
3: '2022-07-28 12:48:37',
4: '2022-07-28 12:49:37',
5: '2022-07-28 12:50:37',
6: '2022-07-28 12:21:37',
7: '2022-07-28 12:52:37',
8: '2022-07-28 12:54:37',
9: '2022-08-01 11:55:40',
10: '2022-08-01 13:56:15',
11: '2022-08-01 13:57:15',
12: '2022-08-01 13:58:28',
13: '2022-08-01 13:59:28',
14: '2022-08-02 08:33:39',
15: '2022-08-02 08:35:39',
16: '2022-08-02 08::39'},
'status': {1: 'Failed',
2: 'Failed',
17: 'Approved',
3: 'Approved',
4: 'Approved',
5: 'Approved',
6: 'Approved',
7: 'Approved',
8: 'Approved',
9: 'Approved',
10: 'Approved',
11: 'Approved',
12: 'Approved',
13: 'Approved',
14: 'Approved',
15: 'Approved',
16: 'Approved'}}
pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I would like to select all the rows in which the `sample_received`, or `order_received` is at least on the 1st of august. What would be the most effective way to do this? The main problem is that it could occur that the 'sample_received' column can have a date that is not mentioned. However, when the 'result_received' column contains a date that is on the 1st of august (in this case) I want the dataframe to include this. Or the other way around.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must provide more details, otherwise you'll just get answers like those in your previous questions.

Comment: @Tobias I actually suggested to open a new question to address the issue of selecting the column, but I agree, as of now the question is no different and should rather be something like "how to select columns with dates automatically". I will close later if there is no update.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I will provide more information regarding the dataset and what I exactly want in a minute.

Comment: Hopefully this indicates it better

Comment: @TimS you really have to make an effort, is the number of columns fixed or not? are the NaNs the only issue? How do you want to handle the NaNs? Provide the expected output (no need for that many rows in the input, 4/5 are enough to demonstrate the issue)

Comment: The number of columns is fixed indeed, just as mentioned in the above dataframe. I just want to make sure that all the rows are included in case that 1 column contains the data of at least (2022-08-01 in this case). Even if this includes an NaN value in one of the columns. Please let me know in case you need more information.

Comment: OK, then my answer to your previous question should already work. Please clarify there if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
cols = df.apply(lambda x: True if x.sample_received >= pd.Timestamp("2022-08-01") or x.order_received >= pd.Timestamp("2022-08-01") else False, axis=1)

df[cols]
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Comment: you should change your `sample_received` and `order_recieved` to `datetime`.
`df.sample_received = pd.to_datetime(df.sample_received)

df.order_received = pd.to_datetime(df.order_received)`

Comment: This one finally did it. Thanks ! Appreciated! : )

Comment: I can't do that yet on this level.

Comment: Apologies for asking. Would it be possible to adjust this code to all dates between 2022-08-01 and 2022-08-14? If so, how?